# How to compress single array using Python OpenCV cv2.PCAProject

Tags: python, opencv, pca

Background: say I have already trained a PCA in python using PCACompute as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

# generate some random data
data = np.random.sample(128)
for x in xrange(63): data = np.vstack((data, np.random.sample(128)))
print data.shape # (64, 128) i.e. 64 arrays of 128 dimensions

# train the PCA
mean, eigenvectors = cv.PCACompute(data, maxComponents=32)
print mean.shape # (1, 128)
print eigenvectors.shape # (32, 128)
```

Problem: now I have a single array that I want to compress using the PCA

```
sample = np.random.sample(128)
print sample.shape # (128,)

compressed_sample = cv.PCAProject(sample, mean, eigenvectors)
```

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (mean.data && eigenvectors.data && ((mean.rows == 1 && mean.cols == data.cols) || (mean.cols == 1 && mean.rows == data.rows)))

Answer (score 1):

Solution: after typing this out I solved it, may as well carry on the post in case anybody else runs into the same issue.

```
sample = sample.reshape((1,128))
compressed_sample = cv.PCAProject(sample, mean, eigenvectors)
```